# CSS Absolute Positioned Table Row and Cell Width with Divs

Tags: css, html-table

I am attempting to build a scheduler using a table and some CSS formatting. The first row of the table, which contains all of the items on the schedule, has absolute positioning, allowing the items on the schedule to display across all of the other rows of the table. The subsequent rows of the table have the time slots.

The problem is the `div`s within the absolute positioned row. If the `div`s are set to `display:block`, they have the appropriate height and overflow behavior, but the second `td` does not span the full width of the rest of the table. If the `div`s have `display:inline-table`, the `td` spans the full width, but the height of the `div`s isn't respected for a smaller table.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.time {
  width: 90px;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.schedule-item {
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  background-color: #e8effc;
  font-size: 10pt;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:800px">
  <table style="width:100%; border-color: #dddddd; position:relative;">
    <tbody>
      <tr style="height:0px; position: absolute; padding: 0px; width: 100%; border-color:transparent;">
        <td class="time" style="border:0px;"></td>
        <td class="si-container" style="text-align:left; padding:0px; border-color:transparent;">
          <div class="schedule-item" style="height:47.5px">
            8:00 AM Amateur Adult Bronze International Standard W/Q Semifinal
          </div>
          <div class="schedule-item" style="height:23.75px">
            8:04 AM Amateur Adult Bronze International Standard Tango Semifinal
          </div>
          <div class="schedule-item" style="height:25px">
            8:05 AM Amateur Adult Newcomer International Standard Waltz Final
          </div>
          <div class="schedule-item" style="height:47.5px">
            8:07 AM Amateur Adult Bronze International Standard W/Q Final
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="height:150px">
        <td class="time">8:00 AM</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="height:150px">
        <td class="time">8:10 AM</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="height:150px">
        <td class="time">8:20 AM</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8bj52wft/)

How can I get the `.schedule-item` blocks to span the full width of the right-hand column? Alternatively, if there is a different construction that accomplishes the same display, I would like to know about that.

Comment: You can add your snippet in a runnable snippet by using `Ctrl+M` next time so that others can run the code more easily ;-)

Comment: Thanks. I'll make sure to do that in the future

Comment: Playing with my code some more, I've come up with a solution, but it doesn't work in Chrome. In Chrome, the sizing of the `td`s in the absolute positioned row is behaving very strangely (e.g., setting the cell sizes to 0% and 100% gets widths of 0px and 513px when the row width is 580px)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to use `position: absolute` to position items inside a table. Instead, set the `div`s to `display: block` and simply place them inside the second `td` of your first row like the following.

Also, try not to set styles using inline CSS. This becomes very hard to maintain when changes happen. An immediate example is your having to type `style:150px;` three times for the rows.

You might have noticed the CSS style: `box-sizing: border-box`. This *must* be added so that the schedule items in the table is displayed still within the table, but expanding its full length. I recommend reading more [about `border-box` here](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/).

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border-color: #dddddd;
  position: relative;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  min-width: 800px;
}

.time {
  height: 150px;
  width: 90px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.schedule-item {
  margin: 2px 0;
  background-color: #e8effc;
  font-size: 10pt;
  padding: 5px 0 0 5px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="row">
        <td class="time">8:00 AM</td>
        <td>
          <div class="schedule-item" style="height:47.5px">
            8:00 AM Amateur Adult Bronze International Standard W/Q Semifinal
          </div>
          <div class="schedule-item" style="height:23.75px">
            8:04 AM Amateur Adult Bronze International Standard Tango Semifinal
          </div>
          <div class="schedule-item" style="height:25px">
            8:05 AM Amateur Adult Newcomer International Standard Waltz Final
          </div>
          <div class="schedule-item" style="height:47.5px">
            8:07 AM Amateur Adult Bronze International Standard W/Q Final
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row">
        <td class="time">8:10 AM</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row">
        <td class="time">8:20 AM</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

---

### Update

Here's the little tweak to the initial solution (for your updated question) by adding a wrapper inside the second column of each row. This wrapper is absolutely positioned, causing it to have the ability to overlap. This wrapper is then filled with the `.schedule-item` `div`s. I've adjusted the height to `130px` so that the overlapping effect is more pronounced.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border-color: #dddddd;
  position: relative;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  min-width: 800px;
}

.time {
  height: 130px;
  width: 90px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.row td:nth-child(2) {
  position: relative;
}

.schedule-items-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px; /* Border width */
  left: 1px; /* Border width */
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2px;
  min-height: 130px;
}

.schedule-item {
  background-color: #e8effc;
  font-size: 10pt;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="row">
        <td class="time">8:00 AM</td>
        <td>
          <div class="schedule-items-wrapper">
            <div class="schedule-item" style="height:47.5px">
              8:00 AM Amateur Adult Bronze International Standard W/Q Semifinal
            </div>
            <div class="schedule-item" style="height:23.75px">
              8:04 AM Amateur Adult Bronze International Standard Tango Semifinal
            </div>
            <div class="schedule-item" style="height:25px">
              8:05 AM Amateur Adult Newcomer International Standard Waltz Final
            </div>
            <div class="schedule-item" style="height:47.5px">
              8:07 AM Amateur Adult Bronze International Standard W/Q Final
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row">
        <td class="time">8:10 AM</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row">
        <td class="time">8:20 AM</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the note about inline CSS. It's still in there because I'm trying to get the code to behave itself. Once I do, I plan to move it to a stylesheet.

Comment: As it turns out, it actually doesn't do what I'm looking for. You'll notice that in your result, all of the divs are inside the second cell on that 8:00 AM row and in the one I posted, they overflow that so that the one ending at 8:11 AM has crossed the top border of the row labeled 8:10 AM. I'm using that top row you omitted as a wrapper for all of the items on the schedule so they can display across the other rows as necessary.

Comment: @Aliden Ah I see. You should probably explicitly mention that in your question, as there is no indicator at all asking for the last schedule item to overlap the first and second row (and the 8:07 made me presume that you want it to be on the first row second cell). If I may know, how are you planning to set the height of the schedule items? Dynamically using JS or is there a fixed value for each minute (e.g. 2 minutes = 2 px)?

Comment: Sure thing. I'll revise the question to make that clear. For now, there's a fixed value for each minute (15px/minute), and I do the calculation on the server to determine how tall each item should be.

Comment: @Aliden Alright, a little tweak should make it work. Your first version of using position absolute is correct. I'll revise my answer later.

Comment: Awesome! I look forward to seeing it!

Comment: @Aliden Updated as per required.